# Printing a Unicode Symbol in C

Tags: c, unicode, ncurses

I'm trying to print a unicode star character ([0x2605](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/index.htm)) in a linux terminal using C. I've followed the syntax suggested by other answers on the site, but I'm not getting an output:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(){

    wchar_t star = 0x2605;
    wprintf(L"%c\n", star);

    return 0;
}
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions, especially how I can make this work with the `ncurses` library.

Comment: Do you have trouble with more common Unicode characters?

Comment: @chux Well, I can print `a` with value `0x0061` but not `ǎ` with value `0x01ce`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Two problems: first of all, a `wchar_t` must be printed with `%lc` format, not `%c`. The second one is that unless you call `setlocale` the character set is not set properly, and you probably get `?` instead of your star. The following code seems to work though:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    wchar_t star = 0x2605;
    wprintf(L"%lc\n", star);
}
```

And for `ncurses`, [just initialize the locale *before* the call to `initscr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15245808/918959).

Comment: This fixed it, thanks! ★ Any ideas how to `mvwprint` this with `ncurses` though?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222466/display-wchar-t-using-ncurses

Answer (score 3):

Whether you are using stdio or ncurses, you have to initialize the locale, as noted in the [ncurses manual](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization).  Otherwise, multibyte encodings such as UTF-8 do not work.

`wprintw` doesn't necessarily know about `wchar_t` (though it may use the same underlying `printf`, this depends on the platform and configuration).

With ncurses, you would display a `wchar_t` in any of these ways:

- storing it in an array of `wchar_t`, and using [`waddwstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addwstr.3x.html), or
- storing it in a `cchar_t` structure (with `setcchar`), and using [`wadd_wch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_add_wch.3x.html) with that as a parameter, or
- converting the `wchar_t` to a multibyte string, and using [`waddstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addstr.3x.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I keep getting an *implicit declaration* error for the wide-character `ncurses` functions, are there some other libraries I need to be including?

Comment: You're missing a `#define`.  Generally that should be _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED`, but most platforms have fubar'd ifdef's: for Linux just use `-D_GNU_SOURCE`.  You'll have to link with `-lncursesw`, but that's not *implicit declaration*

Comment: can you explain a bit more?

Comment: It would be defined using `ncursesw5-config --cflags`, or via a ".pc" file, depending on how ncurses is packaged for your system.