# Implicit declaration of "mvaddwstr" function despite ncursesw (wide variation of ncurses) being explicitly linked

Tags: c, gcc, ncurses, curses

#### Platform

Windows 11 + GCC Compiler 17 (MINGW2)

#### Compilation Command

```
gcc -o main.exe main.c -lncursesw ; ./main.exe
```

#### MINGW2 Include Directory

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\include
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\ncurses
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\ncursesw
```

#### Code

It simply draws a border around the window.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ncurses/curses.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() 
{
    initscr();

    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, row, col);

    wchar_t * square = L"\u2588";

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || i == row - 1)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                mvaddwstr(i, j, square);   
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            mvaddwstr(i, 0, square);
            mvaddwstr(i, col - 1, square);
        }
    }
    
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

### Issue

The compiler seems to believe that `mvaddwstr` is implicitly declared. However, I have explicitly linked the `ncursesw` library in the compilation command (as opposed to the regular `ncurses`).

```
main.c:76:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mvaddwstr'; did you mean 'mvaddstr'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   76 |                 mvaddwstr(i, j, square);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~
      |                 mvaddstr
```

Despite the warning, the program works fine. However, I would like to resolve the warning nonetheless.

#### Attempted Solutions

I have tried to include the `curses.h` file from `ncursesw` in the code. However, the warning persists.

```c
#include <ncursesw/curses.h>
```

I have also tried adding an include to the `ncursesw` directory in the compilation command, but the warning persists.

```
gcc -o main.exe main.c -IC:\msys64\mingw64\include\ncurseswncursesw -lncursesw; ./main.exe
```

- [ncursesw functions not declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59971200/ncursesw-functions-not-declared)
- [Print a wide unicode character with ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834833/print-a-wide-unicode-character-with-ncurses)

Comment: Implicit declaration is a problem while object code is being created, not a link-time problem.  It's saying you've got the wrong header, or the right declarations were not being exposed by the header because you've not set something right.  Or, maybe, you've got a typo in the name (though that seems [unlikely](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mvaddwstr)).

Comment: Does [How to install ncurses on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75556484/how-to-install-ncurses-on-windows) help?

Comment: This answers your question: [ncurses get\_wch() function undeclared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66103288/ncurses-get-wch-function-undeclared) (there are a couple of duplicates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

As outlined in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66103288/ncurses-get-wch-function-undeclared), I simply had to enable wide character support with `NCURSES_WIDECHAR`.

#### Fixed Compilation Command

```
gcc -o main.exe main.c -DNCURSES_WIDECHAR=1 -lncursesw ; ./main.exe
```