# i tried printing unicodes on my eclipse ide but always "?" gets printed

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode

i tried printing unicodes on my eclipse ide but always "?" gets printed

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char c= 0x0900;
    System.out.println(c);
    
}
```

Comment: 1. You might not have that character set loaded.  2. 0x0900 appears to be a modifier of some sort, are you sure it's printable? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_(Unicode_block)

Comment: read this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/43834410/11624647

Comment: Prints OK here. Make sure the font you are using for the console supports Devanagari (look in the Preferences in General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts  - Debug > Console font)

Comment: yes it worked for one of my friend but its not working for me

Comment: yes it  is printable ive tried it for various symbols as well but its not working for my ide i.e, eclipse in my machine