# Output angle symbol in C

Tags: c, unicode, ascii, mingw

I want to create a console application for phasor* addition in C.

I want C to display the **∠** symbol. I don't know how to make C to display UNICODE.
I simply tried `printf("∠");` but it printed a question mark in a box.
I'm using MinGW.

Thanks in advance.

*phasor is an AC electric topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing a Unicode Symbol in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834315/printing-a-unicode-symbol-in-c)

Comment: That  �  question mark in a box could be [glyph 0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/recom#glyph-0-the-notdef-glyph). The ∠ symbol (angle) is e.g. in the `DejaVu Sans Mono` or `Unifont` font…

Answer (score 0):

to print the phasor symbol use `"\u2220"`
if you are using c99

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    puts("\u2220");
}
```

as r3mainer pointed out [Printing a Unicode Symbol in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834315/printing-a-unicode-symbol-in-c)
below code works with c89

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    wchar_t phasor = 0x2220;
    wprintf(L"%lc\n", phasor);
}
```

[check this](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2220/index.htm) for encoding is it UTF-16 or UTF-32

Comment: It gives an error message: "universal character names are only valid in C++ and C99"
and outputs `â^`

Comment: @CingirakliDumbelek are you using c89 ?

Comment: How can I learn which version I'm using?
I just installed MinGW and started coding.

Comment: BTW This wchar_t solution isn't working. It prints a blank space.

Comment: @CingirakliDumbelek are you executing code on cmd , terminal or in ide

Comment: @CingirakliDumbelek edit your question and put your code

Comment: Use `-std=c99` switch on gcc command line.

Comment: I'm using notepad++ and nppexec plugin to run C code. I don't need to post the entire code I guess, I just want to achieve `printf("∠");`  to work. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: @CingirakliDumbelek created a new file type the code that is above check if it runs then we can find what problem is okay