# How do I print a zero width space character in C

Tags: c, character, zero-width-space

I've tried using printf to print a zero width space

`printf("%c", '​');`

I get a warning whenever I try compiling

`warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]`
And when I run the program, I get whitespaces instead of the invisible character, so I placed letters in between the character to see if I get any different results, and it printed nothing
`printf("a%cb\n", '​');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this can be found from this post [Printing a Unicode Symbol in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834315/printing-a-unicode-symbol-in-c)

This will let you print any unicode character if you have the right code for it. In this case the 0 width space is `0x200B`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    wchar_t space = 0x200B;
    wprintf(L"%lc\n", space);
}
```