# Terminal window not able to print out emoji in C

Tags: c

I instructed the code to print out emojis (black and yellow circle)

Instead of printing the emojis it printed these enter image description here does anyone know why and how to solve this? I am quite new too. Help would be appreciated. (i tried searching up on this, but no one really had the same problem as me) I am on windows 11

here is the complete code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


void print_bulb(int bit);

int main()
{
    char message[10];
    do
    {
        printf("Enter ur message: ");
        gets(message);
    }
    while(strlen(message) <= 0 || strlen(message) >= 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(message); i++)
    {
        int decimal = message[i];
        int binary[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++)
        {
            binary[j] = decimal % 2;
            decimal = decimal/2;
        }  

        for (int k = 7; k >= 0; k--)
        {
            print_bulb(binary[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}

void print_bulb(int bit)
{
    if (bit == 0)
    {
        printf("\U000026AB");
    }
    else if (bit == 1)
    {         
        printf("\U0001F7E1");
    }
}
```

I tried putting both the code for the emoji and the emoji itself into the printf function, neither attempts worked. I could also type the emoji in terminal window but when i try running my code it didn't work still. I tried with some other emojis as well, also no effect. I did check my vscode, and it is utf8 encoded so I am really lost.

(btw this was the result when i inputted "H" into my code, ΓÜ½≡ƒƒíΓÜ½ΓÜ½≡ƒƒíΓÜ½ΓÜ½ΓÜ½)

Comment: Never ***ever*** use the `gets` function! It's so [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) it has even been removed from the C language. Use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead. And whatever resource (book, video, tutorial, etc.) that taught you `gets`, throw it away.

Comment: As for your problem, the Windows console have traditionally been pretty bad with handling Unicode. And not all Unicode characters may be available in your glyph set (your font).

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834315/printing-a-unicode-symbol-in-c

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the advice, I didn't know gets is that bad

Comment: Small FYI -- works perfectly over on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4YhdbTajW).  I often use this for a 2nd opinion when I'm wondering is it my code or is it my machine or both or neither?