# Curses library doesn't support wide char on OS X high sierra

Tags: macos, ncurses

OS X 10.13.2 (high sierra).

I'm trying to write simple curses program with widechar support, but it appears, that default (pre-installed library) curses doesn't support widechar:

Simplest program example (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15245808/7936526)):

```
#include <ncursesw/ncurses.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    wchar_t wstr[] = { 9474, L'\0' };
    mvaddwstr(0, 0, wstr);
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

doesn't compile, gives error:

> test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'ncursesw/ncurses.h' file not found

Tried to find in manual pages:

> **man addwstr** 
>   says:

```
   #include <curses.h>

   int addwstr(const wchar_t *wstr);
   int addnwstr(const wchar_t *wstr, int n);
   int waddwstr(WINDOW *win, const wchar_t *wstr);
   int waddnwstr(WINDOW *win, const wchar_t *wstr, int n);
   int mvaddwstr(int y, int x, const wchar_t *wstr);
   int mvaddnwstr(int y, int x, const wchar_t *wstr, int n);
   int mvwaddwstr(WINDOW *win, int y, int x, const wchar_t *wstr);
   int mvwaddnwstr(WINDOW *win, int y, int x, const wchar_t *wstr, int n);
```

As man page says, tried to include "curses.h" instead of "ncursesw/ncurses.h". Again compile error:

> test.cpp:9:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mvaddwstr'; did you mean 'mvaddstr'?

Tried to find any widechar-related curses header in /usr/include. No result. Any suggestions?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77589748/2836621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example (using `<curses.h>`) will work with MacOS if you use a command like this:

```
gcc -o foo -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED foo.c -lncurses
```

That is:

- you have to turn on a definition to make the wide-character features visible (which you could see by reading the header file), and
- the library name is "ncurses" (although it contains the wide-character functions).

Do

```
nm /usr/lib/libncurses.dylib | grep addwstr
```

to see this:

```
0000000000024c39 T _addwstr
0000000000024fba T _mvaddwstr
00000000000254ad T _mvwaddwstr
000000000002580c T _waddwstr
```

As of mid-2018, MacOS ***bundles*** only a very old ncurses library (5.7, released in [2008](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#other_versions)), and a correspondingly old terminal database.  You can see that by

```
$ /usr/bin/tic -V
ncurses 5.7.20081102
```

Interestingly, the dynamic library's filename hints that it is really ncurses 5.4 (another 4 years older), but the compiled-in version shown by **`tic`** and the `curses.h` header file tell the actual version.  As noted, that library contains the symbols which would be needed by the wide-character library.  The name-distinction between ncurses and ncursesw libraries used for most systems predates ncurses 5.4 (again) by a few years, so Apple's configuration would be confusing to most developers.

For ***development*** you should consider using something more recent, e.g., [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=ncurses) or [homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ncurses).  For those, the configuration details are readily available and (unsurprisingly) provide ncurses**w** libraries.

Comment: I tried your method without luck. I included `<ncurses.h>` and `<curses.h>`, then compiled with `g++ -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED  -lncurses test.cpp` but it still complains ```error: no matching function for call to 'waddnwstr'``` . Do you have any idea how to fix this? Am I missing something?

Comment: That should be **`-lncursesw`**

Comment: I tried, but I am on macOs Sierra and there isn't any ncursesw library