# ncurses doesn't support wide char in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, ncurses

I'm trying to run [this code](https://github.com/maksimKorzh/3D-Walk/blob/master/3D-Walk.c) in Xcode.

I get the error for the following function call `mvaddwstr(row, col, shade);`

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'const char *' with an lvalue of type 'const wchar_t *'
Use of undeclared identifier 'mvaddwstr'; did you mean 'mvaddstr'?
Replace 'mvaddwstr' with 'mvaddstr'
```

I followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042203/curses-library-doesnt-support-wide-char-on-os-x-high-sierra) (accepted answer) and compiled the code from command line using

```
gcc -o 3D-Walk -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 3D-Walk.cpp -lncurses
```

This works without any errors. How can I do the same in Xcode?

Comment: The answer you are trying to use has two parts: defining the symbol `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` and linking the library `ncurses`. Which are you having trouble with? [How to define a preprocessor symbol in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367368/how-to-define-a-preprocessor-symbol-in-xcode) or [Linking Libraries in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445815/linking-libraries-in-xcode)?

Comment: Thank you, the code compiles without errors now. Why `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` and not `D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED`?

Comment: The `-` marks the beginning of a command line argument. The letters that follow it identify the type of argument. For example, `-o` means that the output file is coming next, and `-l` means the name of a library is coming next. Sometimes there is a space between the type of argument and the next thing, sometimes not (with no rule that I'm aware of other than read the documentation). A preprocessor symbol is defined by `-D` followed by the symbol to define.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!