# How to print an emoji () in ncurses MacOS

Tags: c++, ncurses

I tried doing this but it just resulted in the emoji not showing on the terminal. It seems like the emoji is replaced with spaces.

Also, I would use the ncursesw library, but it is not supported in macOS and I don't know how to install it.

Output:  `afsdlkja;ljksfd`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int ch;

    initscr();
    raw();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();
    wtimeout(stdscr, 0);
    curs_set(0);

    while (true) {
        erase();
        mvprintw(0, 0, "afsdlkja;ljksfd"); // this

        ch = getch();
        if (ch == KEY_F(1)) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your terminal support emojis? Which terminal are you using?

Comment: @yees_7 Yes, I'm using iterm

Comment: You are using `setlocale()`, however `<locale.h>` is not included. Can you try including it?

Comment: @yees_7 same thing happens. I think locale.h is included in iostream.

Comment: With a bit of research, I think it seems like you need to install ncursesw, but I'm not sure how on your current platform. Since I don't know much about macOS, can you check if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042203/curses-library-doesnt-support-wide-char-on-os-x-high-sierra) helps?

Comment: As I pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042203/curses-library-doesnt-support-wide-char-on-os-x-high-sierra), macOS does have ncursesw as "ncurses", but likely the problem is some rather old bug.  By the way, your program is missing a call to `endwin`.

Answer (score 0):

**Latest Greatest Answer**

For reasons I do not understand, it seems you need a bit more than what I guessed below for C++:

```
# Using homebrew, install "ncurses" and "pkgconfig"
brew install ncurses pkg-config

g++ main.cpp $(pkg-config --libs --cflags /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ncurses/6.4/lib/pkgconfig/ncurses++w.pc) $(pkg-config --libs --cflags ncursesw) -o main
```

---

**Updated Answer**

If you are using C++, you need to use `g++` and `ncurses++w.pc`

```
# Using homebrew, install "ncurses" and "pkgconfig"
brew install ncurses pkg-config

g++ main.cpp $(pkg-config --libs --cflags ncurses++w.pc) -o main
```

---

**Original Answer - actually for C rather than C++**

You can compile `ncurses` programs with wide character support on **macOS** like this:

```
# Using homebrew, install "ncurses" and "pkgconfig"
brew install ncurses pkg-config
```

Then compile `"main.c"` with:

```
gcc main.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ncurses/6.4/lib/pkgconfig/ncursesw.pc) -o main
```

---

If you are unfamiliar with `pkgconfig`, it is a tool which tells the compiler and linker where the necessary header files (for the compiler) and libraries (for the linker) can be found. The settings are usually supplied in a file called `"PACKAGENAME.pc"` by the package developer. You can see what it recommends for  `ncurses` by running:

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ncurses/6.4/lib/pkgconfig/ncursesw.pc
```

You can avoid the long, ugly path by setting an environment variable as follows:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ncurses/6.4/lib/pkgconfig:PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

then you just need:

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags ncursesw.pc
```

and, to compile:

```
gcc main.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags ncursesw.pc) -o main
```

Comment: I'm getting this: `No package '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ncurses/6.4/lib/pkgconfig/ncursesw.pc' found`

Comment: Did you do this `brew install ncurses pkg-config` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. They were already installed.

Comment: Try `find  /opt  /usr -name "ncursesw.pc"` to see if you are on an Intel Mac.

Comment: They are all located in `/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/{VERSOION}/ncursesw.pc` and one of them is `/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig/ncursesw.pc`

Comment: And the C++ one? `find /opt -name "ncurses++w.pc"`

Comment: Here: `/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig/ncurses++w.pc`

Comment: So we're going to aim for something like `g++ main.cpp $(PART1) $(PART2) -o main`

Comment: For PART1, let's try and see what you get with `pkg-config --libs --cflags /opt/local/lib/pkgconfig/ncurses++w.pc`

Comment: it tells me to install something called 'panel'.

Comment: *"panel"* ? I'm lost‍♂️ What's the full message?

Comment: ```Package panel was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `panel.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'panel', required by 'ncurses++w', not found```

Comment: I have no idea now. Maybe `find /opt -name panel.pc`

Comment: here `/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig/panel.pc`

Comment: Ok, try `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig` then try out last attempt at PART1 again.

Comment: How would I do this with CMake?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know as I don't use that. I think we'd have to understand all the switches needed first before using `cmake` to codify and implement the things we find. Try adding the `cmake` tag in order to attract the right experts.

Comment: What do you mean by the cmake tag?

Comment: Also, where are the include paths for ncursesw?

Answer (score 0):

After searching around I found a solution that you don't even need to use `ncursesw`. Just use the unicode escape character like this:

```py
# Convert emoji to unicode escape
s = input()
print(s.encode('unicode-escape').decode('ASCII'))
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int ch;

    initscr();
    raw();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();
    wtimeout(stdscr, 0);
    curs_set(0);

    while (true) {
        erase();

        addstr("\U0001f917 (☞ﾟヮﾟ)☞");

        ch = getch();
        if (ch == KEY_F(1)) break;
    }

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```