# How to print special characters in c++ for mac using ncurses libarary

Tags: c++, macos, encoding, special-characters, ncurses

Now, I want to print special characters in c++ for mac(mojava, 10.14.4), but these characters are broken in my mac book.

I installed ncurses such as `brew install ncurses` and `brew link ncurses`. It can printw English such as `Hello World`, but special characters such as `████████╗███████╗████████╗██████╗ ██╗███████╗` is broken.

### source code

#### setup

```
initscr();
clear();
noecho();
cbreak();
curs_set(0);
```

#### work

```
int startX = 0;
int startY = 0;

mvprintw(startY++, startX, "Hello World");
mvprintw(startY, startX, "████████╗███████╗████████╗██████╗ ██╗███████╗\n");
```

### Result

```
Hello World
?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~U~W?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H
?~U~W?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~U~W?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H
?~U~W ?~V~H?~V~H?~U~W?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~V~H?~U~W
```

Comment: Possible same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703168/adding-unicode-utf8-chars-to-a-ncurses-display-in-c).

Comment: no - it misses a step

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display wchar\_t using ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222466/display-wchar-t-using-ncurses)

Comment: ncursesw can not included on mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for c++ with clang++ for mac(Mojave, 10.14.4).  I think it is using the mac curses rather than the brew installed ncurses. It looks like it needs the locale set: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` For me, this cleared the screen and displayed:

Hello World
████████╗███████╗████████╗██████╗ ██╗███████╗

**Compile cmd:**
    clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Weverything -lncurses *.cpp -o prg

**main.cpp code:**

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();                /* Start curses mode */
    clear();
    noecho();
    cbreak();
    curs_set(0);

    int startX = 0;
    int startY = 0;
    mvprintw(startY++, startX, "Hello World");
    mvprintw(startY, startX, "████████╗███████╗████████╗██████╗ ██╗███████╗\n");

    refresh();                /* Print it on the real screen */
    getch();                  /* Wait for user input */
    endwin();                 /* End curses mode */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is a perfect solution.