# Getting an unexpected character with addch

Tags: c++, linux, ncurses, unreal-engine4

I'm using ncurses with `noecho()`, and I'm trying to print a string from a `TCHAR` (or `char16_t`) array with `addch()` function.

I've tried casting my `TCHAR` to an int, but with the same result.

This is the code I'm using:

```cpp
coords hCursorPosition( GetCursorPosition() );
        if ( hCursorPosition.X == 0 ) return;
        coords nCursorPosition(hCursorPosition.Y, 0);
        SetCursorPosition(nCursorPosition);
        clrtoeol();
        if (!m_sInput.IsEmpty())
        {
            for (auto CharIt(m_sInput.CreateConstIterator()); CharIt; CharIt++)
            {
                const TCHAR Char = *CharIt;
                int intChar = static_cast<int>(Char);
                addch(intChar);
                refresh();
            }
        }
```

`m_sInput` is an `FString` (a type used in Unreal Engine 4), I've checked the `FString` length and it's correct, while the result isn't what I expect.

For example if `m_sInput` is "test", my output will be "test^@"

Comment: You are on Windows, right? This might help: [Display wchar_t using ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222466/display-wchar-t-using-ncurses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`addch`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html) expects a **`chtype`** parameter, which contains an 8-bit character (and if you happen to pass it a `NUL`, it will show that as **`^@`**).

`wchar_t` holds more than an 8-bit character.  Use [`addwstr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addwstr.3x.html) for *that*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Anyway I made a mistake: TCHAR is a char16_t, so I'm getting this compile error when using addwstr: error : cannot initialize a parameter of type 'const char *' with an lvalue of type 'const TCHAR' (aka 'const char16_t')

Comment: Solved replacing the code with this: 
```if (!m_sInput.IsEmpty())
  {
   addstr(TCHAR_TO_ANSI(*m_sInput));
   refresh();
  }```

Comment: @Scienziatogm `TCHAR` is whatever size you tell the compiler to make it. It is intended to make porting code from old DOS-based OSes to Windows NT-based based OSes. A 20-something year old solution to a problem from 20-something years ago. These days it's usually best if you avoid using `TCHAR` to prevent interesting surprises like this one.

Comment: @user4581301 `TCHAR` is defined by Unreal Engine to support a wide range of platforms, and from what I can see in practice it is always defined as `wchar_t`.

Comment: @Rotem Yes, but in this case, it is defined as a const char16_t