# Handling Unicode characters in C and NCURSES

Tags: c, unicode, ncurses

I'm trying to display some unicode characters in a C program. A working MWE can be seen below:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <locale.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();              // Initialize stdscr

    for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        switch (x%5)
        {
            case 0:
                mvaddstr(1, x, "\u2588");
                break;
            case 1:
                mvaddstr(1, x, "\u2593");
                break;
            case 2:
                mvaddstr(1, x, "\u2592");
                break;
            case 3:
                mvaddstr(1, x, "\u2591");
                break;
            case 4:
                mvaddstr(1, x, " ");
                break;
        }
    }

    mvprintw(3, 0, "Press ANY KEY to finish");
    refresh();
    int ch = getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

To compile use `gcc -o shades shades.c -lncursesw`. It compiles fine and shows the shades correctly, as we can see in image below.

[image: shades]

But instead using a `case/switch` statement I would like put my characters into an *array* of hexadecimal codes and iterate over it. As the shameful attempt below.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();              // Initialize stdscr

    uint shades[5] = { 0x2588,
                       0x2593,
                       0x2592,
                       0x2591,
                       ' '};

    char utfchar[7];

    for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        sprintf(utfchar, "\\u%04x", shades[x%5]);
        mvaddstr(1, x, utfchar);
    }

    mvprintw(3, 0, "Press ANY KEY to finish");
    refresh();

    int ch = getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Here I'm using `sprintf` to convert the hexadecimal value into a string formatted as `\u0000` where `0000` are the correct hexadecimal value. Then I use `mvaddstr` as I did in previous code, since `mvaddstr` expects a `const char *` in third argument.

This is one of the many failed attemps. I'm not being able to copy the strings correctly in unicode format, neither being able to use a variable as argument to `mvaddstr` when I try to add unicode content.

I would like to know how can I format the unicode capable `const char *` from a `uint` valid unicode hex value to insert it into the `mvaddstr`?

PS: I'm not using C++ just plain C in Linux. C++ solutions are not a solution

Comment: Maybe change the array to `const char * shades[5] = { "\u2588", "\u2593", "\u2592", "\u2591", ""};`

Comment: Parsing of escape sequences in strings and characters (like `"\u2588"`) is done at *compile-time*, by the compiler itself. You can't create escape sequences at run-time. As for what e.g. `"\u2588"` is doing, it's simply inserts the hexadecimal number `0x2588` into the string at that point (byte order indeterminate).

Comment: There is no function in C to encode a hex value into a valid unicode? Anyhow the idea to use a `const char` array works. But since the character values are semi-dinamically generated in my code. I would like to be able to *encode*  hex values into valid unicode characters at run time.

Comment: You can use `wchar` functions as long as your system and locale expect `wchar` to hold a unicode code point. Ncurses has wide character support; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222466/display-wchar-t-using-ncurses, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply put the strings in your array:

```c
const char *shades[] = { "\u2588",
                         "\u2593",
                         "\u2592",
                         "\u2591",
                         " "};

for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
{
    mvaddstr(1, x, shades[x%4]);
}
```

If you want to do it with codepoints, you need to encode it as UTF8 (or anything NCurse expects):

```c
void sprintutf8(char *buffer, uint32_t code)
{
    if (code < 0x80)
        sprintf(buffer, "%c", code);
    else if (code < 0x800)
        sprintf(buffer, "%c%c",
            0xC0 | (code >> 6),
            0x80 | (code & 0x3F));
    else
        sprintf(buffer, "%c%c%c",
            0xE0 | (code >> 12),
            0x80 | (code >> 6 & 0x3F),
            0x80 | (code & 0x3F));
}

[...]

for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
{
    sprintutf8(utfchar, shades[x%4]);
    mvaddstr(1, x, utfchar);
}
```

Comment: I don know about intern details of unicode specifications. Is this code machine endian safe? There aren't any standard C functions to handle unicode encodings?

Comment: this code is endian safe as it uses bitwise operators. there was attempts to get widechar in C which was IMHO not well handled and i'd recommend not going that route (search about wchar_t if you want to anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `wctomb` casting with `wchar_t` to convert from hex to unicode:

```
uint shades[5] = { 0x2588,
                   0x2593,
                   0x2592,
                   0x2591,
                   ' '};

char utfchar[MB_CUR_MAX];

for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
{
    memset(utfchar, 0, sizeof utfchar);
    wctomb(utfchar, (wchar_t)shades[x % 5]);
    mvaddstr(1, x, utfchar);
}
```